# Undeleted Twitter photos after account deactivation

Tags: twitter, privacy

I deactivated my Twitter account, but when I search for my @screenname in Google, I see some pages that includes my Twitter photos.

For example: `example1.com/twitterusers/screnname.html` page includes my photo which has this URL:

```
http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/123456/my_photo_normal.jpeg
```

How can I delete this photo? Because it is shown in Google SERPs.

Answer (score 1):

Much like many other popular web services (Facebook, Instagram, ect.), Twitter maintains the rights/ownership to any content you post, possibly indefinitely.  From their most current 'Privacy Policy' posted online:

> When using any of our Services you consent to the collection, transfer, manipulation, storage, disclosure and other uses of your information as described in this Privacy Policy

They also go on to say...

> Tweets may be searchable by search engines and are immediately delivered via SMS and our APIs to a wide range of users and services, with one example being the United States Library of Congress, which archives Tweets for historical purposes. 
>   When you share information or content like photos, videos, and links via the Services, you should think carefully about what you are making public.*

I do however see that those links you posted are no linger good, so you may have already managed to get them down, Congrats!